# knockout: observable array not getting binded properly - only 1 result being shown while api returns 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

[Html code with knockout binding](https://jsfiddle.net/nkqk1s37/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.toggleCarousel', function () {
                D_usedSearch.similarCarsCarousel.showCarousel($(this));
            });

showCarousel: function (toggleBtn) {
            var carouselMain = toggleBtn.parent().find('div.similarCarCarousel');
            var carouselList = carouselMain.find('li');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/webapi/profileRecommendations/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: 'profileId=' + toggleBtn.parents('li').find('a').eq(3).attr('profileid'),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('sourceid', '1'); },
                    success: function (response) {
                        D_usedSearch.similarCarListings(response);
                    }
                });
              });
        }
```

similarCarListings : ko.observableArray([])

The api returns 6 objects but only one is shown in ui.

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong? I am new to knockout? do i need to apply binding or do something else too?

Comment: Is the _"only one"_ that is shown in the UI the one that you're using as a template? Have you called `ko.applyBindings` ?

Comment: no i have not used ko.applyBindings? Where and why do i need that?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you have written this data-bind:

```
foreach: D_usedSearch.similarCarListings
```

The `<li>` that comes after this data-bind acts as a template that knockout uses to render a list item for every item in an array named `similarCarListings`.

Knockout will not touch the HTML until you tell it to do so, by calling `ko.applyBindings`. This method needs at least one argument: a "Viewmodel" that contains all the information it needs to render your UI.

The data-bind you've written would need at least the following viewmodel (VM) to work:

```
var vm = {
  D_usedSearch: {
    similarCarListings: ko.observableArray([])
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

In your `success` handler, you provide the observable array with new items:

```
success: function (response) {
  vm.D_usedSearch.similarCarListings(response);
}
```

Let me know if this helps out. If you haven't applied your bindings yet, you might run in to some errors...

Here's an example of the knockout stuff *without all the things that have nothing to do with knockout*:

```js
var exampleServerData = [{
  ProfileId: "0",
  CarName: "Car Name 0",
  OriginalImgPath: "http://img.carwale.com/used/no-cars.jpg",
  Price: "1000$",
  Url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
  Km: "40000",
  Fuel: "LPG",
  MakeYear: "2000",
  AreaName: "Area 0",
  CityName: "City 0"
}, {
  ProfileId: "1",
  CarName: "Car Name 1",
  OriginalImgPath: "http://img.carwale.com/used/no-cars.jpg",
  Price: "2000$",
  Url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
  Km: "30000",
  Fuel: "LPG",
  MakeYear: "1000",
  AreaName: "Area 1",
  CityName: "City 1"
}];


var vm = {
  D_usedSearch: {
    similarCarListings: ko.observableArray([])
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);


// This goes in your success callback
vm.D_usedSearch.similarCarListings(exampleServerData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: D_usedSearch.similarCarListings">

  <li data-bind="attr: { id: 'SimilarListing-' + $index() }">

    <img data-bind="attr: { 
                    profileId: ProfileId, 
                    alt: CarName, title: CarName, 
                    'src': OriginalImgPath }">

    <div data-bind="text: Price"></div>
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: Url }, text: CarName"></a>

    <p>
      <span data-bind="text: Km + ' km'"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: Fuel"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: MakeYear"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span data-bind="text: AreaName"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: CityName"></span>
    </p>
  </li>
```

Comment: My case is a little different. I have this 'toggleCarousel' class inside loop so i will have to bind it for all. I tried:

  $(".toggleCarousel").each(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(D_usedSearch.similarCarListings, this[0]);
    });

This gives error. Is this correct way to bind?

Comment: If you pass the `observableArray` to `applyBindings`, the array itself becomes the viewmodel (and you'd have to bind using `foreach: $data`). I'd suggest to render a static list first so you get a feel for how knockout works. Once this list renders without problems, you can continue adding the carousel functionality...

Comment: I tried with placing multiple <li> elements with hard coded values. Its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/t77Lqp5v/

sorry this is not indented code.

Comment: I've added an example of how the knockout part of your question works. I think you need to put some work into providing an example that shows all parts of your code, without all the stuff that's not relevant to the problem. Right now, there's not much more I can do to help...